# netcore LoaderException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rider

I am building services targeting .NetCore20. I am building these services using JetBrains Rider on CentOS 7.6.

I have a very strange problem on one of my solutions with a library that is used in many other solutions without any problem.

The screenshot shows the full error thrown: 
[image]

So if I have a look at my `.csproj` file it shows the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ.Serilog" Version="2.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Context" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Redis" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="BediDto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BediLibs\BediDto\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BediDto.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="BediModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BediLibs\BediModels\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BediModels.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="BediTools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BediLibs\BediTools\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BediTools.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="BizBus.CommonEnums, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BizBusLibs\BizBus.CommonEnums\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BizBus.CommonEnums.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="BizBus.Commons, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BizBusLibs\BizBus.Commons\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BizBus.Commons.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="OperationsManagerServer.ServiceModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\BizBusOpsManagerServer\OperationsManagerServer.ServiceModel\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\OperationsManagerServer.ServiceModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BizBusDataExchangeServer.ServiceModel\BizBusDataExchangeServer.ServiceModel.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The assemblies not found are `BediDto` and `BediModels` but of course both are there and also in the `bin` folder of the project:

```
[tbednarz@linuxdev-tbws2 netcoreapp2.0]$ pwd
/home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0
[tbednarz@linuxdev-tbws2 netcoreapp2.0]$ ls -all | grep Bedi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz  16384 Jul 19 15:39 BediDto.dll
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz   3528 Jul 19 15:39 BediDto.pdb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz  15872 Jul 19 15:39 BediModels.dll
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz   4632 Jul 19 15:39 BediModels.pdb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz   6144 Jun  4 16:54 BediTools.dll
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tbednarz tbednarz   1096 Jun  4 16:54 BediTools.pdb
```

What I don't like in the project files are the relative paths (....\BediLibs.....) Is this still valid at runtime, I don't know....

The code fails no matter whether it is started in the debugger or as docker container...

Any idea what is wrong? Are there any old cached files somewhere that I might need to delete manually??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Since @mythz was replying, I have some more details about the place where the exeption is thrown. Here is the last code in ServiceStack:

`ServiceController.cs` has a method `public ServiceController Init()` and then a method `private List<Type> GetAssemblyTypes(Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)`. Inside this method there is a loop

```
foreach (Assembly assembliesWithService in assembliesWithServices)
{
    str1 = assembliesWithService.FullName;
    foreach (Type type in assembliesWithService.GetTypes())
    {
        if (!this.appHost.ExcludeAutoRegisteringServiceTypes.Contains(type))
        {
            str2 = type.GetOperationName();
            typeList.Add(type);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I catch is thrown in this statement:

```
str1 = assembliesWithService.FullName;
```

See screenshot 2 with the details: 
[image]
If I step into that statement, I endup in .NET code, a file called `Assembly.cs` and there in the following method:

```
public virtual Type[] GetTypes()
{
  Module[] modules = this.GetModules(false);
  int length1 = 0;
  Type[][] typeArray1 = new Type[modules.Length][];
  for (int index = 0; index < typeArray1.Length; ++index)
  {
    typeArray1[index] = modules[index].GetTypes();
    length1 += typeArray1[index].Length;
  }
  int destinationIndex = 0;
  Type[] typeArray2 = new Type[length1];
  for (int index = 0; index < typeArray1.Length; ++index)
  {
    int length2 = typeArray1[index].Length;
    Array.Copy((Array) typeArray1[index], 0, (Array) typeArray2, destinationIndex, length2);
    destinationIndex += length2;
  }
  return typeArray2;
}
```

The statement `typeArray1[index] = modules[index].GetTypes();` is the one that causes the crash. And here I can also see the `FileNotFound` exception with my library:
[image]

So the question is why this happens. I use this in many other projects without a problem, so it is very strange, but maybe the code gives other developers with deeper know-how on the .Net stuff an idea where I could investigate further...

**UPDATE 2**

I distribute my software as docker images. To build them I currently use some bash scripts. Here is the one I use in the 'problem'-solution to generate a LOCAL image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
publishdir=publish
localimagename=bbinvoiceserver
if [ -d ${publishdir} ]; then
  printf "Target directory (%s) already exists, deleting it ...\n" ${publishdir}
  rm -rf ${publishdir}
fi
dotnet publish -c "Debug" -o ${publishdir}
# create docker image
docker build -t ${localimagename} -f dockerfile.debug .
if docker image ls | grep -q '<none>'; then
    printf "Removing temporary images (<none>   <none> ones)....\n"
    docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
fi
docker image ls
rm -rf ${publishdir}
```

And the output from 'dotnet publish' is:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.82.30579 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.csproj...
  Restoring packages for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.csproj...
  Restoring packages for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel/obj/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 441.69 ms for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.csproj.
  Generating MSBuild file /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface/obj/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/obj/BizBusInvoiceServer.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 949.69 ms for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.csproj.
  Restore completed in 978.09 ms for /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.csproj.
  BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.dll
  BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel/publish/
  BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.dll
  BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface/publish/
  BizBusInvoiceServer -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/BizBusInvoiceServer.dll
  BizBusInvoiceServer -> /home/tbednarz/Projects/BizBusInvoiceServer/BizBusInvoiceServer/publish/
```

And if I list the content of the `publish` folder it contains all those files it complains not to be able to find at runtime:

```
[tbednarz@linuxdev-tbws2 publish]$ ls -l
total 10224
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  273408 Jun 18 13:00 AutoMapper.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   16384 Jul 19 15:39 BediDto.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz    3528 Jul 19 15:39 BediDto.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   15872 Jul 19 15:39 BediModels.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz    4632 Jul 19 15:39 BediModels.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz    6144 Jun  4 16:54 BediTools.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz    1096 Jun  4 16:54 BediTools.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   10752 Jul 18 14:40 BizBus.CommonEnums.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz     240 Jul 18 14:40 BizBus.CommonEnums.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   44032 Jul 18 14:40 BizBus.Commons.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   15812 Jul 18 14:40 BizBus.Commons.pdb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tbednarz tbednarz   59392 May 29 09:15 BizBusDataExchangeServer.ServiceModel.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tbednarz tbednarz   16712 May 29 09:15 BizBusDataExchangeServer.ServiceModel.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz  130372 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.deps.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   27648 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz    5800 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz     146 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.runtimeconfig.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz  273408 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   66832 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceInterface.pdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   94720 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   24488 Jul 20 08:45 BizBusInvoiceServer.ServiceModel.pdb
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  186368 Jan 11  2018 CommandLine.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   92672 May  1  2017 DnsClient.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   22008 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  124912 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   15352 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   73712 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   78840 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   38384 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   31728 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  276464 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   15864 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   93688 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   83440 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   66544 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   19960 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   24056 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   20984 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   24560 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   19960 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   22000 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   23544 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   36360 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   44552 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   17904 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   31216 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   39408 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   14320 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   46584 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   30704 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   17928 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   26104 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   33288 Apr  6 16:09 Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   71152 Apr 24 00:44 Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  451072 May 16 22:31 MongoDB.Bson.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  632320 May 16 22:31 MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  639488 May 16 22:31 MongoDB.Driver.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  639488 Jun 18  2017 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   87552 Jul 16 14:59 OperationsManagerServer.ServiceModel.dll
-rw-rw-r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   23292 Jul 16 14:59 OperationsManagerServer.ServiceModel.pdb
drwxrwxr-x 15 tbednarz tbednarz    4096 Jul 20 08:45 runtimes
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz    8192 Mar  7 06:12 Serilog.AspNetCore.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  116736 Dec  3  2017 Serilog.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz    6656 Jan 14  2018 Serilog.Enrichers.Context.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz    5120 Nov 13  2016 Serilog.Enrichers.Thread.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   27136 May  1 08:16 Serilog.Exceptions.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   11264 Aug 18  2017 Serilog.Extensions.Logging.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz    8192 Jul  5  2016 Serilog.Formatting.Compact.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   32768 Oct 22  2017 Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   26624 Oct 29  2017 Serilog.Sinks.File.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz 1088512 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  189440 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Client.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  411136 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Common.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz 1517568 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  138240 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  575488 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.OrmLite.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  286208 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Redis.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz  398848 Jan  2  2018 ServiceStack.Text.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   32504 Jul 19  2017 System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   21944 Apr  6 16:09 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
-rwxrw-rw-  1 tbednarz tbednarz   28568 Jul 25  2017 System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 tbednarz tbednarz   60808 Apr  6 16:08 System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
```

As you can see the files `BediModels.dll` and `BediDto.dll` are at the top.

Comment: Have you any problem in NuGet restore in Rider?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. What do you mean with 'problem'? It is not a NuGet problem, the library is one of my own and I do not have them in NuGet packages.

Comment: In sdk projects nuget restore make packages.assets.json with all project dependencies not only NuGet. Could you build your project from console?

Comment: I use `dotnet publish` in a bash script which creates and pushes my docker images. This works just fine without any problem. I will update the original message with more details in a minute.....

Comment: Updated with UPDATE 2

Answer (score 0):

If these are project references you should reference the project instead:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\BediLibs\BediDto\BediDto.csproj" />
```

Comment: Hmm, it is a project in a DIFFERENT solution. That solution has 12 projects containing a lot of my own libraries. I don't know how I can add a project reference from another solution, at least in Rider I don't see a way to do it..

Comment: I have updated the original message with some more details about the place where it crashes.

Comment: @ThommyB Couldn't tell you what the issue is anymore than the error message where it says it can't find the BediDto assembly. You can reference projects in another solution, you just need to also include references to all the projects they reference as well. But if you're going to reference .dll's directly I'd recommend putting them in a local `/lib` folder and have a script to copy them instead of trying to reference projects output folder.

Comment: Yeah sounds like I need a CI tool soon, otherwise it gets more and more uncomfortable to build all that stuff.....

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this in a 'quick and dirty' way by simply adding the two DLLs to the 'root' project (even though these libs are not requied there directly) and now it works. So following @mythz recommendation

> But if you're going to reference .dll's directly I'd recommend putting them in a local /lib folder and have a script to copy them instead of trying to reference projects output folder.

seems to be the way to go. But I believe this is a bug somewhere in the `dotnet` build tools which seem not to correctly resolve all dependencies correctly (at least under some unknown circumstances...) These kind of problems are usually pretty hard to find since they are almost never properly reproducable...